# Can you programmatically refresh CA certificates inside the CTX in OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, certificate, ca

Have a long running server application, with long running sessions.  The server application enforces client authentication and reads in a CA certificate, including a CRL at server startup time.  Daily the new CA certificate and CRL is uploaded and the server must pickup the changed CA and CRL.  Today, the server tears down the CTX and restarts a new CTX....however, since there are long running sessions, the CTX memory is still being held by the OpenSSL package (until the reference count goes to zero).

Looking for a way to programmatically refresh the CA / CRL into the same server CTX.  Looks like any CA certificate used by OpenSSL is cached within the CTX.  Is this true?  We don't see an API to flush this cache even though a new CA certificate was loaded on the file system, we cannot seem to load it in to use it.  Even though we issued a SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations or SSL_set_client_CA_list...the OpenSSL code always seems to reuse the cached version of the previous CA certificate read in from file.

So the question...is there a way to load in a new CA certificate from file into an existing CTX?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the current certificate store for the context and free it.

```
void clear_certificate_store(SSL_CTX *context) 
{
    X509_STORE *certificate_store = NULL;

    if (context == NULL) 
    {
        return;
    }

    current_store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(context);
    X509_STORE_free(current_store);
}
```

**NOTE:** `X509_STORE_free` actually only decrement the reference count of the object and free it only if the reference count is 0.